# Culture specific sort order in Azure SQL with Entity Framwork

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure-sql-database

I am trying to sort a query according to the user culture, but I cannot find how to do that! How is it done?

For now, always sorting according to Swedish culture (se-SV) would be sufficient, but my guess is that it is also possible to set this per connection or per query.

I generate the database from and EDMX model and would also like to specify the default db culture if possible, but mainly i want to set it per connection.

Thanks!
/Victor